# Solving $T(n) = T(3/5 n + 1) + n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I would need a help for this recurrence:
$$
T(n) = T\bigl(\tfrac{3}{5} n + 1\bigr) + n^2.
$$
I tried with iterative method and substitution method but I failed. I'm a beginner in solving recurrences, and I would be grateful if you could help me.

EDIT:Guys I apologize for being unclear, I had taken some things for granted. This is a computer science problem. I have to found the big O notation.
This is all my information, usually the professor gives us the recurrence and tells us to solve it with any studied method. I still apologize.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Show us what you tried, don't tell.

Comment: Also, what's your base case?  Do you know $T(0)$ or $T(1)$?

Comment: @Gianfranco Terrazzano Are you trying to solve this exactly or just in regards to Big $O$? Where did this problem come from? Is it a math class or computer science class by any chance?

Comment: You don't give an initial condition my friend!

Comment: I haven't T(0) or T(1).

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal You mean $T(n)\in\frac{25}{16}n^2+O(n)$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to square the 3/5 in that geometric series :(

Comment: You give me the impression that you are passing through an assigned exercise without having digested the problem yourself.  Math.SE aims to help students of mathematics at all levels, but you should start from asking Questions for which you can judge the correctness using your existing understanding.  Otherwise I don't think we can help you learn from your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

For big $n$ we have

$$
T(n) \approx T\left(\frac 35 n\right) + n^2
$$

so asymptotically we have $T(n)\approx \alpha n^2$ with $\alpha$ calculated according to

$$
\alpha n^2 \approx \alpha\left(\frac 35 n\right)^2+n^2
$$

then

$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{\left(1-\left(\frac 35\right)^2\right)}
$$